# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'mic_permission') in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to check whether microphone permission is granted or not using this code:

```js
navigator.permissions.query( { name: 'microphone' } ).then(function(permissionStatus) {

  console.log(permissionStatus.state); // granted, denied, prompt
  if(permissionStatus.state != 'granted')
  {
    this.mic_permission=false;
    alert('Please allow your microphone');
  }

  permissionStatus.onchange = function(){
      console.log("Permission changed to " + this.state);
  } 
});
```

but getting this error:

> core.js:6486 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set
> properties of undefined (setting 'mic_permission') TypeError: Cannot
> set properties of undefined (setting 'mic_permission')

at this line  `this.mic_permission=false;`

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @YongShun I tried this link solution but it was not working

Comment: Try: `navigator.permissions.query( { name: 'microphone' } ).then(permissionStatus => { /* Implementation */ });`

Comment: @Yong Shun Thanks it's working

Comment: Unlike regular functions, arrow functions do not have their own this . The value of this inside an arrow function remains the same throughout the lifecycle of the function and is always bound to the value of this in the closest non-arrow parent function. In your case when you need to refer to a property defined in your component class, arrow function works and regular function refers to the callback function of then under permissions.query